# Navicat installation Error -libmysql_d.dll

Tags: sqlite, dll, windows-10, navicat

I am trying to install **Navicat** on windows 10 for SQLite purpose. 
Here is error shown while starting install --click on `navicat.exe` file[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just restart the system and it will work fine . error is coming  due to  not find the path of sqllite file in C drive.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Do you have anything to back your answer ? If restarting does not solve the OP's problem, then this is not a valid answer. Maybe you wanted to leave a comment instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently issue.The directly and quickly resolution is re-install the [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/download).

You can also try to search the file 'libmysql_d.dll' in your environment or try to find it in the Navicat install folder, and copy it to 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\'.
for 64-bit version of Window, otherwise, please copy to 'C:\Windows\System32'.

You can also download it from http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=libmysql.dll&arch=32bit&version=. and copy.

Comment: I'm still trying to install first time, basically i'm using to install existing version of navicat not premium.

Comment: I have tried copy-paste libmysql.dll files into both \System32 and install folder. 
I think it's need for 'libmysql_d.dll' instead. found no where.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 home and am seeing this as well. I've a) restarted the computer; b) reinstalled Navicat; c) found sqlite.dll in the Navicat folder; d) found libmysql_d.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\, and I'm still seeing the error. It does work on my Windows 10 Pro computer (for now), but I should be able to use them both, interchangeably.

Comment: To try to restart your computer after reinstall navicat as the article.
http://rocinantesoftware.blogspot.com/2016/02/missing-sqlitedll-when-launching-navicat.html

Comment: @Sunteen Wu you got the wrong link, here is the correct one: https://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=libmysql_d.dll&arch=32bit&version=&dsc=

Answer (score -1):

then you can uninstall the navicate and again install the navicate than it will work fine thanks